# Lumen file upload

Tags: php, laravel, api, file, lumen

I have the following code for the file upload :

```
$picName = $request->file('cnicFrontUrl')->getClientOriginalName();
$picName = Carbon::now() . $picName;
$destinationPath = '/uploads/user_files/cnic';
$request->file('cnicFrontUrl')->move($destinationPath, $picName);
```

In my public folder i have `uploads/user_files/cnic`.

The exception i receives :

```
{
  "message": "Could not move the file \"D:\\xampp\\tmp\\php2D1C.tmp\" to \"uploads/user_files/cnic\\2017-05-22 09:06:15cars.png\" ()",
  "status_code": 500
}
```

**Whats missing here ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "uploads/user_files/cnic\2017-05-22 09:06:15cars.png\"

The issue is the destination slashes. Directory separator on windows is `\`

Also, `:` is not allowed in file name

Comment: So what should i change ?

Comment: make sure to enter correct destination path. and check if the folder exists. see [rename()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php)

Comment: ah, and ":" is not allowed in filenames

Comment: the file is not moving

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
        $picName = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $picName = uniqid() . '_' . $picName;
        $path = 'uploads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'user_files' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'cnic' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $destinationPath = public_path($path); // upload path
        File::makeDirectory($destinationPath, 0777, true, true);
        $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $picName);
```

We can not set file name like this

> 2017-05-22 09:06:15cars.png

So use uniqid() function for unique file name of image

Answer (score 1):

use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of / or \, this will automatically get independent directory separator for your platform.

example

```php
<?php

// will output "../public/logo.png" in unix or "..\\public\\logo.png"
$path = ".." . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "public" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "logo.png"
echo $path;
```

Reference : [php.net - Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/dir.constants.php)